# Why did the prophet PBUH break the fast early?

Tags: sawm

This hadidth says that the prophet PBUH did not wait for proper maghrib time to break his fast [Sahih Al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/62) hadith

> We were in the company of the Prophet (PBUH) on a journey and he was
>   fasting, and when the sun set, he addressed somebody, "O so-and-so,
>   get up and mix Sawiq with water for us." He replied, "O Allah's
>   Apostle! (Will you wait) till it is evening?" The Prophet (PBUH) said,
>   "Get down and mix Sawiq with water for us." He replied, "O Allah's
>   Messenger (PBUH)! (If you wait) till it is evening." The Prophet (PBUH) said
>   again, "Get down and mix Sawiq with water for us." He replied, "It is
>   still daytime."(1) The Prophet (PBUH) said again, "Get down and mix Sawiq
>   with water for us." He got down and mixed Sawiq for them. The Prophet
>   (PBUH) drank it and then said, "**When you see night falling from this side,
>   the fasting person should break his fast.**"

Prophet said "night falling from this side", was it maghrib time yet? And if not, why could he break the fast?

Comment: The english translation is not very accurate - in arabic it reads much clearer and basically conforms to the rule to break fast on Maghrib.

Comment: All I see about the time is when it says "when the sun set". May be you can provide more accurate translation in your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a translator (and not a scholar) and translating Quran/Hadith is a very big responsibility.

Comment: @Yahia btw the person who translated this hadith was an scholar.

Comment: perhaps a scholar but perhaps not a translator...

Answer (score 1):

> "When you see night falling from this side, the fasting person should break his fast."

We don't know where he was pointing at, and the exact time of the day that was, it was not very clear that it was maghrib already or not.

But luckily, through a different chain of narration, we have [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/61), which is the hadith in the same book immediately proceeding what you referenced.

> حَدَّثَنَا الْحُمَيْدِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا سُفْيَانُ، حَدَّثَنَا هِشَامُ بْنُ عُرْوَةَ، قَالَ سَمِعْتُ أَبِي يَقُولُ، سَمِعْتُ عَاصِمَ بْنَ عُمَرَ بْنِ الْخَطَّابِ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ إِذَا أَقْبَلَ اللَّيْلُ مِنْ هَا هُنَا، وَأَدْبَرَ النَّهَارُ مِنْ هَا هُنَا، وَغَرَبَتِ الشَّمْسُ، فَقَدْ أَفْطَرَ الصَّائِمُ ‏"‏‏.‏
>   Narrated Umar bin Al-Khattab: Allah's Apostle said, "When night falls from this side and the day vanishes from this side and the sun sets, then the fasting person should break his fast." Sahih Al-Bukhari Volume 3, Book 31, Hadith 175.

The same was for the hadith immediately after what you referenced:

> حَدَّثَنَا مُسَدَّدٌ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الْوَاحِدِ، حَدَّثَنَا الشَّيْبَانِيُّ، قَالَ سَمِعْتُ عَبْدَ اللَّهِ بْنَ أَبِي أَوْفَى ـ رضى الله عنه ـ قَالَ سِرْنَا مَعَ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم وَهْوَ صَائِمٌ، فَلَمَّا غَرَبَتِ الشَّمْسُ قَالَ ‏"‏ انْزِلْ، فَاجْدَحْ لَنَا ‏"‏‏.‏ قَالَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ، لَوْ أَمْسَيْتَ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ انْزِلْ، فَاجْدَحْ لَنَا ‏"‏‏.‏ قَالَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ، إِنَّ عَلَيْكَ نَهَارًا‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ انْزِلْ، فَاجْدَحْ لَنَا ‏"‏‏.‏ فَنَزَلَ، فَجَدَحَ، ثُمَّ قَالَ ‏"‏ إِذَا رَأَيْتُمُ اللَّيْلَ أَقْبَلَ مِنْ هَا هُنَا فَقَدْ أَفْطَرَ الصَّائِمُ ‏"‏‏.‏ وَأَشَارَ بِإِصْبَعِهِ قِبَلَ الْمَشْرِقِ‏.‏
>   We were traveling with Allah's Messenger (PBUH) and he was fasting, and when the sun set, he said to (someone), "Get down and mix Sawiq with water for us." He replied, "O Allah's Messenger (PBUH)! (Will you wait) till it is evening?" The Prophet (PBUH) again said, "Get down and mix Sawiq with water for us." He replied, "O Allah's Messenger (PBUH)! It is still daytime." The Prophet (PBUH) said again, "Get down and mix Sawiq with water for us." So, he got down and carried out that order. The Prophet (PBUH) then said, "When you see night falling from this side, the fasting person should break his fast," and he beckoned with his finger towards the east.
>   Sahih al-Bukhari Book 30, Hadith 63

And so was [this](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/65).

> حَدَّثَنَا أَحْمَدُ بْنُ يُونُسَ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو بَكْرٍ، عَنْ سُلَيْمَانَ، عَنِ ابْنِ أَبِي أَوْفَى ـ رضى الله عنه ـ قَالَ كُنْتُ مَعَ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فِي سَفَرٍ، فَصَامَ حَتَّى أَمْسَى، قَالَ لِرَجُلٍ ‏"‏ انْزِلْ، فَاجْدَحْ لِي ‏"‏‏.‏ قَالَ لَوِ انْتَظَرْتَ حَتَّى تُمْسِيَ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ انْزِلْ، فَاجْدَحْ لِي، إِذَا رَأَيْتَ اللَّيْلَ قَدْ أَقْبَلَ مِنْ هَا هُنَا فَقَدْ أَفْطَرَ الصَّائِمُ ‏"‏‏.‏
>   I was with the Prophet (PBUH) on a journey, and he observed the fast till evening. The Prophet (PBUH) said to a man, "Get down and mix Sawiq with water for me." He replied, "Will you wait till it is evening?" The Prophet said, "Get down and mix Sawiq with water for me; when you see night falling from this side, the fasting person should break his fast."
>   Sahih al-Bukhari Book 30, Hadith 65

So what you referenced was one among the many about the same situation, where Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) told his follower when to end the fast: After sun sets, and night comes. He did not break his fast, there is no reason to believe that he did either.

Comment: @meshang all the hadith you quotes says the same thing as my quoted hadith. In all of them, the prophet is asked to wait till proper time and prophet said no. Not sure if your quoted hadith answers my question?

Answer (score 1):

[Verse 128 from Surah Al-Baqarah](http://quran.com/2/187) explains when to start/break your fast(take a note of the the bold words):

> أحل لكم ليلة الصيام الرفث إلى نسائكم هن لباس لكم وأنتم لباس لهن علم الله أنكم كنتم تختانون أنفسكم فتاب عليكم وعفا عنكم فالآن باشروهن وابتغوا ما كتب الله لكم وكلوا واشربوا حتى يتبين لكم الخيط الأبيض من الخيط الأسود من الفجر ثم أتموا الصيام إلى الليل ولا تباشروهن وأنتم عاكفون في المساجد تلك حدود الله فلا تقربوها كذلك يبين الله آياته للناس لعلهم يتقون
>
> It has been made permissible for you the night preceding fasting to go to your wives [for sexual relations]. They are clothing for you and you are clothing for them. Allah knows that you used to deceive yourselves, so He accepted your repentance and forgave you. So now, have relations with them and seek that which Allah has decreed for you. And eat and drink until the white thread of dawn becomes distinct to you from the black thread [of night]. Then **complete the fast until the sunset**. And do not have relations with them as long as you are staying for worship in the mosques. These are the limits [set by] Allah , so do not approach them. Thus does Allah make clear His ordinances to the people that they may become righteous.

and from the hadith you quoted, The man thought you should only break your fast when you don't see the light of the sun. but the prophet broke his fast to teach him that he can break his fast when it is sunset.

I hope this clears the confusion